# PHP Bug with Conditional Operator?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

```
$i=0;
$j='00:15';

if ($i==$j)
    echo "equal";
else
    echo "not equal";
```

displays equal?

Comment: user `if ($i === $j)` instead of `if ($i==$j)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the === is problematic

for example 10===10 will be false if one is integer and one is string even though they are identical as can happen from forms posting.

the solution i used was:

if ("$i"=="$j")

this way it just checks if they're identical regardless of type

Comment: This shows a misunderstand in PHP's equality operators. == checks that the two operands are equal; 10 == "10" will return true. === checks that the two operands are equal, and of the same type, therefore 10 == "10" will return false, but 10 === 10 will return true. There's no need to wrap both in double quotes in your 'solution'.

Comment: I thought so too. but came across a bug. Where x==y was giving false. after adding the quotes, it worked.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, it's due to PHP implicitly casting the variables. You can see this if you run on the command line: `php -r "var_dump((int)'00:15');"` The string 00:15 is cast to an int (0) and then 0 is compared to 0.

Comment: will try to reproduce the problem. has been a couple of days. was weird. I remember that both in string representation printed as "10" but for some bizare reason If I used the == operator it gave false. Adding quotes fixed the issues.

Answer (score 6):

`00:15` is cast into an integer first and then compared with `$i`. Since `intval()` (which does the casting) stops at the first non-numeric character, `00:15` is cast into zero, which is equal to zero. No bug here, this is how the `==` operator works.

If you want to avoid casting, use `===` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `==` the types will be converted before they are compared. In this case, both will be converted to an integer, and when you convert a non-numeric string to an integer, it will probably result in `0`.

If you use the `===` operator instead, you will get the result that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

string and int compares as int's, So `$j` converts to 0 here because starts with 00

Answer (score 0):

Not bizarre at all - when comparing string with integer, the first one is being cast to integer then compared. Use `===` for type checking and you'll see the real result